# How to extract data based on Index from a Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset and i need to extract data from a column based on the Index position

The SERVICE_NAME column contains "ISPFSDPartnerPubSub/4_2/ProxyServices/InboundAndOutbound/AP/InboundPartnerCommunicationsAPLPPS"
I will need to extract based on 4th and 5th Index as 'colX' and 'colY'

How can i achieve it?

```
val log = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("quote", "\"")
      .option("multiLine", "true")
      .load("OSB.csv").cache()
val logs = log.withColumn("Id", monotonicallyIncreasingId()+1)
val df = spark.sql("select SERVICE_NAME, _raw from logs")
```

Expected Output
Col X: AP
Col Y: InboundPartnerCommunicationsAPLPPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** for select string parts specified by index, such code can be used:

```
val df = Seq("ISPFSDPartnerPubSub/4_2/ProxyServices/InboundAndOutbound/AP/InboundPartnerCommunicationsAPLPPS").toDF("SERVICE_NAME")
val result =
  df
    .withColumn("splitted", split($"SERVICE_NAME", "/"))
    .select(
      $"splitted".getItem(4).alias("colX"),
      $"splitted".getItem(5).alias("colY")
    )

result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+----------------------------------+
|colX|colY                              |
+----+----------------------------------+
|AP  |InboundPartnerCommunicationsAPLPPS|
+----+----------------------------------+
```

Soluion for columns by index: 
Selecting two columns by column indexes, with renaming, can be done in this way:

```
df.select(
  col(df.columns(4)).alias("colX"),
  col(df.columns(5)).alias("colY"))
```

Comment: In df.columns it should be the actual column name which is SERVICE_NAME8. ?

Comment: Yes. In answer "df" means Dataframe, "df.columns" - return array of dataframe columns: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#columns--

Comment: i get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 when i use your logic.

Also how can i escape '/' in my string?

Comment: Looks like just string parts are required, please look on updated answer.